# Creating an instance from String in Java

Tags: java

If I have 2 classes, "A" and "B", how can I create a generic factory so I will only need to pass the class name as a string to receive an instance?

Example:

```
public static void factory(String name) {
     // An example of an implmentation I would need, this obviously doesn't work
      return new name.CreateClass();
}
```

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Class c= Class.forName(className);
return c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();//assuming you aren't worried about constructor .
```

- [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

For invoking constructor with argument

```
 public static Object createObject(Constructor constructor,
      Object[] arguments) {

    System.out.println("Constructor: " + constructor.toString());
    Object object = null;

    try {
      object = constructor.newInstance(arguments);
      System.out.println("Object: " + object.toString());
      return object;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      //handle it
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      //handle it
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      //handle it
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      //handle it
    }
    return object;
  }
}
```

have a [look](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ObjectReflectioninvokeconstructorwithparameters.htm)

Comment: How can I send arguments to the constructor?

Comment: `System.out.println(e);` Please, NEVER! Why don't you simply declare the exception? When you *really* feel like being able to handle it by reporting, use `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: newInstance() is deprecated now, replaced with clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look at [Reflection](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ObjectReflectioncreatenewinstance.htm):

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SampleNoArg {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Rectangle r = (Rectangle) createObject("java.awt.Rectangle");
      System.out.println(r.toString());
   }

   static Object createObject(String className) {
      Object object = null;
      try {
          Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
          object = classDefinition.newInstance();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
      return object;
   }
}
```