# Android - Create a instance of a class and calling from String

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create a instance of a class from a fragment activity in android.

The main fragment (what I am calling from adapter) is like this-

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3,container,false);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

And what I am doing in my **Fragment Adapter** is just calling the class.

So if I am calling like it-

```
Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
return (Fragment) tab3;
```

And it is working just fine. But I need it to be dynamic, because I need to have dynamic tabs with names stored in a String.

So, I found a solution to do that from this question answer-

[Creating an instance from String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767088/creating-an-instance-from-string-in-java)

And I am trying something like this-

```
            String className = "Tab3";
            Object tab3 = null;
            try {
                tab3 = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return (Fragment) tab3;
```

It is showing Error when I am going to that tab/fragment.
Error log is-

```
07-14 16:13:10.952    1069-1069/com.appnucleus.slidingtabbedview E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:116)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:869)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:250)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class.forName()` needs the fully qualified name - that is, the name of the package the class is contained in, plus the simple name of the class itself.

Assuming the package containing the class is called `com.your.package`, the code would have to be:

```
String className = "com.your.package.Tab3";  // Change here
Object tab3 = null;
try {
    tab3 = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return (Fragment) tab3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object o = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

But your `className` should be fully-qualified - i.e. `com.package.MyClass`