# How to dynamically call a method on a qualified service?

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface as following:

```
public interface Solver {
    void execute(final String definition);
}
```

I have several solver implementations. For example:

```
@Qualifier("naive")
@Service
public class NaiveSolver implements Solver {
    @Override
    public void execute(final String definition) {
    }
}

@Qualifier("optimal")
@Service
public class OptimalSolver implements Solver {
    @Override
    public void execute(final String definition) {
    }
}
```

Now, in my database I have the data for these solvers as following:

```
type:       textual - examples: simple, naive
definition: textual
```

When fetching this data, I need to map the `type` column to the actual service instance, so it can solve the provided `definition`.

So, my question boils down to this: how can I, given a `type` string, get the instance of the corresponding `Solver` service instance of which the qualifier is equal to that `type`? I believe that `@Autowired` cannot be used here, as I need to find beans dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Spring 4 you can autowire multiple implemetations into a Map where bean qualifier is a key, and the bean itself is a value

```java
@Autowired
private Map<String, Solver> solvers;

void doStuff() {
    String type = ... // obtain type
    Solver solver = solvers.get(type);
    solver.execute(...)
}
```

**Update**

Correct way of naming a bean is not

```
@Qualifier("naive")
@Service
```

but

```
@Service("naive")
```

`@Qualifier` is used along with `@Autowired` to ensure the correct bean is injected

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("naive")
private Solver naiveSolver;
```

Comment: This works, this is an awesome feature! Thank you for showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create configuration which will just hold mapping to your solvers:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("optimal")
private Solver naiveSolver;

@Bean
public Map<String, Solver> mapSolver() {
   Map<String, Solver> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("naive", naiveSolver);
   return map;
}
```

Or even going further you can follow factory pattern which will provide you different instances of solvers.

Another way you can dynamically get those beans from application context.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the application context already holds all beans, with their possible qualifiers. So while I could manage my own map, I believe that's re-inventing what the application context already is doing. So in other words: I am interested in how to find the qualified service from the application context. Could you please show me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the following solutions:

- [How to inject dependencies into a self-instantiated object in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813588/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-a-self-instantiated-object-in-spring)
- [Creating an instance from String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767088/creating-an-instance-from-string-in-java)

  ```
  private @Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
  public void doStuff() {
     Class c= Class.forName(className);
     MyBean obj  = c.newInstance();

     beanFactory.autowireBean(obj);
     // obj will now have its dependencies autowired.
  }
  ```